# Error/Warning message printed in terminal Not able to create launch.json file in vscode

Tags: c++, powershell, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am using Vscode for the first I have configure the path for C++ as mention on official website and with reference to stack overflow and executed "hello-world" program it worked fine but when I try to debug the code it gives some message  in terminal and "launch.json" file is also not created. I tried to search it but was not able to find something useful I have attached the Message in the description below can anyone please help or guide me what exactly the meaning of that message is or it is an warning or error.
CODE:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "welcome" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Below is the message which got popup link to the image and

[PS D:\C++ Programs>  & 'c:\Users\vaibh.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.11.5-win32-x64\debugAdapters\bin\WindowsDebugLauncher.exe' '--stdin=Microsoft-MIEngine-In-kacu4rno.cdv' '--stdout=Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-1rkd2imu.beo' '--stderr=Microsoft-MIEngine-Error-fv0ekrpg.lb3' '--pid=Microsoft-`enter code here`MIEngine-Pid-ysq2ay2t.1se' '--dbgExe=C:\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe' '--interpreter=mi'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1yod.png)

Comment: Not your question, just some general advice. Creating paths with spaces in them like `D:\C++ Programs` is just asking for trouble. Too often the space gets treated as the end of the path, and so whatever command it is part of does not work.

Comment: Please (also) post your code, data, error messages as ([properly formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)) _text_, [not (just) as _images_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/45375).

Comment: [For many good reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4581301) you should only use images when the question is about the image (you have a graphics rendering problem) or the picture is literally worth a thousand words (you have an image of a GUI configuration pane).

Comment: What you're seeing is the debugging command I'd expect to be used _behind the scenes_, not to show up in the integrated terminal. I have no explanation, but avoiding working dirs. that contains spaces and characters such as `+` is worth a try.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @mklement0

 when I try to debug above code there is a message in terminal which I have highlighted with red color in the image as well as the link to the image is the message which get pop up in the terminal and the run and debug window is open instead of creating the launch.jason file. and when I click on "run and debug" button in the window the same message gets pop up again which I have mentioned in the question and highlighted in the image i am using Vscode version 1.70.2